# How can I make a short screen as a pop-up menu?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I attached a sample screen shot taken from the Skype app.  How can I replicate the pop-up menu?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJVPW.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance of [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/). [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uiactionsheet_uiactionsheetdelegate/) is an tutorial on how to use it.